# Creating a property of Type Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

Why cant i do something like this?

This is the proerty in the logger class

```
public Dictionary<string, string> customProperties
        { get; set; }
```

This is the property in the interface...

```
 Dictionary<string, string> customProperties
        { get;  set; }
```

and then call it like this...

```
DatabaseLogger.ILogger logger = new DatabaseLogger.Logger();

logger.customProperties.Add("companyName", "Company");
logger.customProperties.Add("application", "application");
```

I am getting a `NullReferenceExcpetion` - how can I avoid it?

Comment: What makes you think you can't do that?

Comment: You absolutely can do that. You just need to initialize your dictionary object first. See Oded's answer below

Comment: There is no question here. Only a statement that is **not** backed by supporting evidence (error message, exception, etc.)

Comment: Sorry there should have been a question mark after the first sentence. Also I saved the question before putting in the error. I was getting a Null ref exception. The below answer fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing missing is initialization of the property - it is `null` otherwise (meaning that calling `Add` on it will throw a `NullReferenceException`).

```
DatabaseLogger.ILogger logger = new DatabaseLogger.Logger();

logger.customProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
logger.customProperties.Add("companyName", "Company");
logger.customProperties.Add("application", "application");
```

Though this might be better done in the `Logger` constructor:

```
public Logger()
{
  customProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
}
```

Comment: it wouldnt let me answer for some reason until i waited 4 minutes or something like that.